# Bigrams and collocations in Python to achieve the below output in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

```
tokenizedword = nltk.regexp_tokenize(textcontent, pattern = r'\w*', gaps = False)
tokenizedwords = [x.lower() for x in tokenizedword if x != '']
tokenizedwordsbigrams=list(nltk.bigrams(tokenizedwords))
stop_words= set(stopwords.words('english'))
tokenizednonstopwordsbigrams=[(w1,w2) for w1 , w2 in tokenizedwordsbigrams
if (w1 not in stop_words) and (w2 not in stop_words)]
cfd_bigrams=nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(tokenizednonstopwordsbigrams)
mostfrequentwordafter=cfd_bigrams[word].most_common(3)
tokenizedwords = nltk.Text(tokenizedwords)
collocationwords = tokenizedwords.collocation_list()
return mostfrequentwordafter ,collocationwords
```

I get the output as
[('fans', 3), ('car', 3), ('disciplines', 1)]
[('sports', 'car'), ('sports', 'fans')]

But the expected output is
[('fans', 3), ('car', 3), ('disciplines', 1)]
['sports car', 'sports fans']

Can anyone help where am I going wrong with the above code?

Comment: Please add your raw data.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

collocationwords=[' '.join(i) for i in tokenizedwords.collocation_list()]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).